# How do I change the value of a variable inside of a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, function, variables

I want to change the value of a variable. I tried the following method but it does not work:

```
    function MapData() {
      var  bbs=0 ;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/subfactors/BBth",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                bbs = result;
               }
            }
        });
        return bbs;
    };
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: _...change the value of a variable...._ What variable? What change? You have to be a bit more specific. So what do you want to achieve and what doesn't work with your code?

Comment: @B001 I think he wanted to change the variable **"bbs"** value

Comment: Duplicate:
Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Comment: My Ajax returns a float  that shows when alerted. I want the value of the returned number to be equal to the value of the bbs.

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous, so you need to wait for it to complete:

```
async function MapData() {
    var  bbs=0 ;
    bbs = await $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/subfactors/BBth",
        type: "GET",
    });
    return bbs;
});
```

and then when you call it:

```
let bbs = await MapData()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use callbacks (or some other way to handle async behavior) (your ajax request is async, and therefore your return is happening before the request completes.

```
function MapData(cb) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/admin/subfactors/BBth",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        cb(result)
       }
    }
});

function cb(result) {
    console.log(result)
}

MapData(cb)
```